# google oauth1 to oauth2 migration invalid_token error

Tags: google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I have been trying to obtain new oauth2 refresh tokens using oauth1 access token but it constantly returns an "invalid_token" error. I have checked and the access token is working correctly. I have also tested the same creds/params in oauth2 playground and result is the same. Any help is appreciated...

Here is the curl verbose output:

```
> POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Authorization: OAuth oauth_nonce="cb7407355fe20f509cb6bf901eae2d24", oauth_timestamp="1389169471", oauth_consumer_key="***", oauth_token="1%2FFVy....", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="0YL1hH5R571nOH1byeHxQlg%2Fa6g%3D"
Content-Length: 444

* upload completely sent off: 444 out of 444 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
< Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 08:24:31 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
* Server GSE is not blacklisted
< Server: GSE
< Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host accounts.google.com left intact
string(415) "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Wed, 08 Jan 2014 08:24:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "error" : "invalid_token"
}"
```

Comment: Thank for reporting the problem. I am looking into this, will update this thread ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are putting the client_secret in {} in the POST Body?

grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:migration:oauth1&client_id=xxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=**{xxxxxxx}**

You will also need to put {} around the client_secret value when you are generating the oauth_signature

Answer (score 0):

We have made a few changes to the validation pieces of the OAuth1->OAuth2 token migration. Would you mind checking your migration flows again and updating this thread with the results?